# How to animate scrolling from first page to another etc

Tags: javascript

i created 4 div Anchors : yak0, yak1, yak2, yak3 in my html file. From yak0 to yak1 - first page, from yak1 to yak2 - second page etc. I want  to animate scrolling from first page to another etc when user will scroll pages. i wrote some code but something is wrong. Because pages shake up and down like spring.

```js
window.onscroll = function() {

 var teg0 = document.getElementById("yak0");
 var teg1 = document.getElementById("yak1");
 var teg2 = document.getElementById("yak2");
 var teg3 = document.getElementById("yak3");

 var h = document.documentElement.clientHeight;

 var hi0 = 0;
    var hi1 = hi0+h;
    var hi2 = hi1+h;
 var hi3 = hi2+h;

 if (window.pageYOffset > hi0 && window.pageYOffset <= hi1) 
  $('body').animate({scrollTop: $(teg1).offset().top}, 1000);
 

  if (window.pageYOffset > hi1 && window.pageYOffset <= hi2 ) 
   $('body').animate({scrollTop: $(teg2).offset().top}, 1000); 

     if (window.pageYOffset > hi2 && window.pageYOffset <= hi3 ) 
  $('body').animate({scrollTop: $(teg3).offset().top}, 1000);  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The scrolling is a progress, and the each progress you set with animate 1000ms. So your code is runing blocked with the animate. I guess you have thousands of 1000ms waiting progresses, so it doesn't work, cause the runing didn't finished;

Maybe you can try this, and test that:

```
$('body').animate({scrollTop: $(teg1).offset().top}, 1000, function(){
     console.log('----let me see this runing how many times----')
```

});

Or set the interval by 1ms, and checkout the result...